# How to call function of parent html page of an iframe(having swf from which to call function) by ExternalInterface from Flex?

Tags: javascript, flash, apache-flex, externalinterface

i want just know if it's possible with ExternalInterface call methods declared in a html page different from where the caller swf is located.

Example: i have a video.swf into a test.html and another page script.html. I want to call a method declared into script.html from video.swf instantiated into test.html. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

by calling parent we will have access out of the IFrame context. plz call

```
ExternalInterface.parent.someFunctoin();
```